# What happens when you @ the community user on a post

Tags: support, community-user, comment-replies

Just curious. What happens when you @ the Community user?

Comment: SE dev Nick Craver in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user/19739#comment351111_19739): "This is going to dissapoint, but *technically* Community is just a constant of -1 in a file somewhere..."

Comment: I've read that, but what happens?

Comment: What happens? .... We all get an inbox message ...

Comment: What, every user on Stack Overflow would be alerted?

Comment: Yes! Awesome, right?

Comment: Wow. Now I want to try it. 

Comment: Now I wonder what state a post needs to be in so that community can be mentioned and it will work

Comment: Maybe make an important comment on a big post, get 1000 upvotes on your comment, and delete your account.

Comment: I think this question should be migrated to meta.se

Comment: How does that happen?

Comment: folks, can you clarify why would anyone VTC the post as "not reproducible, typo, or obsolete" - at least to me this case looks like an incorrect usage of the close reason?

Comment: @OlegValter on SO main it has the subtext "unlikely to be helpful to future readers" maybe related to that

Comment: @Nick huh, may as well be (help center wording not helping in clarifying either), thanks. Off-note: still think it should not be used in this case, though - and I think I am [not the only one who](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405918/11407695) considers the close reason in a strict sense - being so localized it is unlikely to help others.

Comment: The close reason for this post doesn't make any sense to me. There's no described behavior to reproduce, or to be rendered obsolete; the question is simply asking how some aspect of the site works, which seems to be on-topic. I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 13):

There are some strict rules which users can be @-replied to, as explained in [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

As the Community User is not really a user (as [mentioned by Jeanne Dark](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405990/what-happens-when-you-the-community-user-on-a-post#comment831211_405990)) you will not find Community on questions or answers on SO (but Sebastian was kind enough to dig one up on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336174/158100) <sup>1</sup>). Nor did the Community user comment on posts or dupe hammer any questions on SO (but they had plenty of fun on MSE).

So that leaves us with Edits and Bounties.

Community does do Edits. For example: [Python how to make simple animated loading while process is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029562/python-how-to-make-simple-animated-loading-while-process-is-running/61602308#61602308)
So you can @-reply Community there.

And it turns out that Community does take control over bounties as well, for example on [I imrotate() an image, draw two lines, rotate back the lines and draw them in orginal image, but don't get the expected result in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421612/i-imrotate-an-image-draw-two-lines-rotate-back-the-lines-and-draw-them-in-or) so on that question you can @-reply the Community user as well.

Now if you ever get a response remains to be seen. You might get flagged by some angry post owners that will also get notified in their inbox of every comment while you experiment reaching Community.

As far as I know it is not possible in production for an SE dev to impersonate as a user and although Community has an actual credential it is unlikely someone will actively check the inbox (but if they answer or ask a question or comment I guess they will check their inbox messages first). In the rare case they do, you better make sure you have sent them a lovely and caring message. After all we care for Community.

If you want to dig a bit further where Community played a role, I've used this [quick SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1385103) to get some data.

---

1. Technically that MSE answer was re-attributed to Community (so it was posted first by an actual user and after posting its owneruserid was re-attributed to -1)

Comment: I'm trying to do it.

Comment: Did it work, @SebastianSimon?

Comment: @Anonymous Did what work? All users getting a message? No, because that was a joke.

Comment: "_Nor did the Community user comment on posts_" On MSE there are two comments: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161538/are-there-any-robot-moderators-on-so/161544#comment469239_161544), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237001/why-does-stackstatus-follow-ryan-seacrest/237002#comment777117_237002)

Comment: @Ivar Try to trigger it.