# Should questions that appear to reflect a genuine misunderstanding be closed as typos?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I recently answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66986506/how-to-solve-unknown-database-error-in-java) where the OP appears to have been genuinely confused about how to write a MySQL connection string (they were mixing connection strings for file-based databases and for server-based databases).

However, the question was recently closed for being a typo.

My question, then: does this question actually deserve to be closed? More generally, should (non-trivial) questions where the OP appears to have a genuine conceptual misunderstanding be closed as typos?

Comment: I don't know anything in the subject matter. Do you think someone with the same error has any chance of finding that question and its answers later?

Comment: @Kaiido I think that they may be able to find it based on the error message - if someone else had the same confusion, they'd probably end up with a similar error.

Comment: This is basically the same question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405916 and my answer would be the same. If the misunderstanding is something other programmers could have, then the question is useful, and shouldn't be closed as a typo.

Comment: @cigien You, know these silly beginner questions, where c++ newbs completely confuse pointers with arrays, vectors and alike? Well, for these ones we have suitable dupes to clarify, but sometimes I also tend to close such question as a typo, if the misunderstanding is too basic.

Comment: @cigien Yeah, it does look like that one's quite similar - I'll mark mine as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, I do understand the desire to close those questions as typos (it's easier than spending time finding the right canonical targets), but I try to remind myself that too basic is not really a reason to close a post (I don't come up with these rules ;)). This doesn't include things like a missing `;` of course, I close those as typos.

Comment: @cigien In the recent day I've seen an op asking if `for(...) { new char[100]; /* ... */  }` does correctly allocate the memory they need to input something inside the loop. I don't know if you've seen that. I think I used _typo_ as close reason for that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, I don't recall seeing that one in the last few days. Not knowing the exact question, I'm not sure what action, if any, I would have taken. But I won't deny that there have been questions that I've VCTed as a typo because none of the other reasons fit. My concern is that those weren't necessarily appropriate closures, and so I generally try to avoid taking any action in those cases (I'll downvote them often, but that's a separate thing).