# Non-first question in first question review queue

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, specific-audit

I came across [this item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/32511672) in the *[First questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review)* review queue.

It was

- Not the first question of the user,
- [Removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73158562/sql-server-why-substring-returns-a-bunch-of-characters-when-start-position-and-e) 20 days ago.

It probably is one of those *are you paying attention?* questions.

- Tags look OK,
- Generally nicely formatted.
- Reproducible,
- One spelling mistake,
- Horizontal scroll bar and perhaps an unnecessary image.

I skipped the review and was not taking chances with these instant bans. What was the correct action to take?

Comment: If you'd come across this question outside of a review queue what actions would you have taken?

Comment: I personally think that's a bad audit, that question got closed as typo but its a misunderstanding one can easily have. Relevant: [Should a question with a misunderstanding be closed as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405916/should-a-question-with-a-misunderstanding-be-closed-as-not-reproducible-or-was)

Comment: Do you mean what would have been the correct action had you not skipped?

Comment: Yes, It was an audit.  You should provide feedback to the author with regards to what problems exist in the question.  Selecting "share feedback" would pass the audit.

Comment: @PeterMortensen exactly - as I'd say an edit would be too minor, but the question itself is answerable. Yet, I know the post has been removed, so any action taken would be meaningless.

Comment: Choosing to pass is a very valid option for audits. Basically, you passed the test, no matter how.

Comment: @RobertLongson The context of it being in a review queue is relevant. It is obviously an audit meant to test the reviewer. However, I think this one is not as clear-cut as most of those audits. I would not upvote it, not edit it (too minor), *perhaps* leave a comment, although there is some argument to be made for any of those 3. So, since I'm unsure, the action would be inaction, as I've done here. I'm querying what the intended action is, as SecurityHound pointed out above.

Comment: @AndrewT. While valid, it is not a satisfying choice, especially for an obvious audit. [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/1091465) argues reviewers are presented with posts known to be of high or low quality, this one, in my opinion, is neither, hence asking here what the intended action is, to *hone the skill*.

Comment: "and was not taking chances with these instant bans" - there is no such thing as an instant ban. You need to fail multiple audits before you get sent on holiday.

Comment: @SecurityHound Well, I don't know if the author needs additional feedback about the typo.  Assuming one agrees that it's a typo, flagging or voting for closure would be the best option.

Comment: @RyanM - Right; "Share Feedback" allows you to vote to close.  I was just pointing out that was the correct option to select.

Comment: @SecurityHound While the "Share feedback" options mirror some of the close reasons, it doesn't actually vote to close; it's only for posting a comment.  To vote to close, you have to click the "Close" link, vote to close, then submit the review with "Other action".